# Theme suggestion or theme overridden

Tags: 7, theming

I have two template override - **user-profile.tpl.php** and **views-view-fields--myviewname.tpl.php**.
To take effect those templates, I had to place them into the default enabled theme.

The main problem is that I use the default theme "bartik" and I got to place them into "themes/bartik/templates/" to let the drupal theme system know them.
I know it is not a good idea because it is just like hacking. I should use a custom theme or sub-theme from bartik, but I don't want to write any theme.

The only clue is that I have a custom module and I shall put them into that module ( sites/all/modules/mymodule/templates ). Then, I shall make a theme suggestion to let the theme system use them.

How can I do this or any better idea?

Comment: have you cleared the cache ? Because some times it creates problem if cache is not cleared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this using [hook_theme_registry_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7). I placed my theme files in **sites/all/modules/mymodule/theme** and then altered the theme registry with the hook.

```
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry){
    if( isset($theme_registry['user_profile']) ){
        $theme_registry['user_profile']['template'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule').'/theme/user-profile';
        $theme_registry['user_profile']['theme path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule').'/theme';
    }
}
```

Comment: You have overridden the theme registry not suggesting new theme.

Comment: Yes, but this is how I resolved. If you have better solution, please post it as answer. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

when you create a sub-theme you do not need to create any "new" template, but you can change something from the "main-theme". So try to create a new sub-theme and put that files into sub-theme.

M.